# Loop to add all 26 letters into s using set Template Class

Tags: c++, for-loop, set, template-classes

I'm studying for a exam next week and I've come across a question in my book that I can't get to work. Says that suppose `set<char> s;` is declared now write a loop to insert all 26 letters into s.

What I've got is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
     s.insert('A') + i;
}
```

Something similar to this would work for an array I believe, but not for this template class.
I know I don't have to insert each letter I just don't know how I could run through the alphabet.

Comment: `('A') + i` -> `('A' + i)`.

Comment: Lol well this is awkward... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For portability, don't assume that uppercase letters have contiguous encodings; there are character encodings where your code would not work correctly. Instead:

```
const char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    s.insert(letters[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    s.insert(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
 s.insert('A') + i;
```

as

```
 s.insert('A' + i);
```

or

```
 s.insert(65 + i);   // 'A' value in ASCII table is 65
```

or as answered by user31264

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    s.insert(c);
```

you can test by printing all element using:

```
for (auto e:s)
    cout << e;
```